# WinRAR batch file for compressing the first subdirectory in each folder into a zip

Tags: batch-file, winrar

I'm struggling to get a solution in place to scan all folders in a directory, and create a zip file within said folders of the contents of the first/only subfolder therein.

here's an example folder/structure/heirarchy

`I:\Unsorted\Sony - PlayStation Vita\NoNpDrm Physical\SENRAN KAGURA SV [PCSE00398] [NTSC]\PCSE00398`

I'd like to get the contents inside of `PCSE00398` compressed into a zip (of the same name) and left in the `I:\Unsorted\Sony - PlayStation Vita\NoNpDrm Physical\SENRAN KAGURA SV [PCSE00398] [NTSC]` folder.

Comment: powershell would be easy: `get-childitem -path "I:\..." | foreach-object { get-childitem -path $_ | select-object -first 1 | foreach-object { $_ } }` the second $_ contains the first folder so you can do your winrar command there.

Comment: Wait, I missed that its the only subfolder. Then cmd's `forfiles` or `for /f` can both be used too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bat
@echo off 

set "_flag=a -ep1 -m5 -cfg- -y -o+"
cd /d "%~dp0" && for /d /r "I:\test\." %%i in (*
)do 2>nul tree.com /a "%%~dpnxi"|findstr /bl \\--- >nul || (
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" %_flag% "%%~i" "%%~dpni" |find/i ".rar" )
```

---

To reach the last level of a subfolder, it is only necessary to check if in each subfolder there is another folder there, otherwise, compact this last level folder.

You can use the `for /d /r` loop, which will go through all the folders, and in each folder inside the loop, use the `tree` command together with `findstr`, where you can check if the current folder has or not more subfolders.

- ```bat
  FOR /R - Loop through files (recursively)
  FOR /D - Loop through several folders/directories
  ```
- ```bat
  The option /D /R is undocumented, but can be a useful combination,
  while it will recurse through all subfolders the wildcard will only
  match against Folder/Directory names (not filenames)
  Note: Source linked to ss64.com
  ```

You can use the `tree "current_looping_folder" /a` in all subfolders recursively with **`for /d /r`**, and by checking each output with **findstr "string"** (**`"\---"`**) redirecting to the operator **`||`** and take action (**`Rar`**) if **not found** this string `\---` in command `tree` output `\---Last Folder`:

```bat
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is A0AD-DC56
F:\SUPER_USER\Q1599429
\---Last Folder
```

The above output is from the folder where I am, `F:\SUPERUSER\Q1599429` and here we have the `Last Folder` subfolder, but if I am in the `F:\SUPER_USER\Q1599429\Last Folder` subfolder, I get the output below:

```bat
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is A0AD-DC56
F:\SUPER_USER\Q1599429\Last Folder
No subfolders exist
```

If `findstr` do not find the string `"\---"`, I have no subfolder in current folder, this is the last folder:

```bat
F:\SUPER_USER\Q1599429\Last Folder
```

In this case, if there is no subfolder, the command `tree "Actual_Loop_Folder" /a | findstr "\---"` command will not succeed, then making the operator `||` execute the `Rar.exe` command exactly in your last folder of the actual folder level...

- **Obs.: 1** The additional `\` is required for escaping the character `\` in `findstr`

```bat
 ... tree.com /a "%%~dpnxi"|findstr /bl \\--- ...
```

- **Obs.: 2** This will try to illustrate how the `||` operator works mechanically:

```bat
                         command1 || command2
                 execute command1 || only execute command2 (if) command1 fails
          if tree folder /a fails || there is no subfolder in it
      there is no subfolder in it || this is the the last subfolder
       this is the last subfolder || run rar flags in the \Last Folder
tree /a "%~fi"|findstr "\---">nul || Rar "I:\Unsorted\...\PCSE00398"
```

- **Obs.: 3** If you need to run with **`WinRar.exe`** instead `Rar.exe`, just remove/replace/edit:

```bat
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" %_flag% "%%~i" "%%~dpni" |find/i ".rar"

"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRar.exe" %_flag% "%%~i" "%%~dpni"
```

- **Obs.: 4** You can edit for to use your custom flags/switches for your **`Rar/WinRar`** command:

```bat
<Commands>
        a    ==  Add files to archive 

<Switches>

      cfg-   ==  Disable read configuration 
      ep1    ==  Exclude base directory from names 
  m<0..5>    ==  Set compression level (0-store...3-default...5-maximal) 
   o[+|-]    ==  Set the overwrite mode 
        y    ==  Assume Yes on all queries 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
set "_flag=a -ep1 -m5 -cfg- -y -o+"
```

---

- Some further reading:

[√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

[√] **[For /D Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**

[√] **[For /R Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**

[√] **[WinRar.exe | Rar.exe /?](https://www.winrar-france.fr/winrar_instructions_for_use/english.html)**

[√] **[CMD/Bat Operator /dostips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8123)**

[√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

Comment: thank you for this.  was much more involved than I had expected it to be.  I sincerely appreciate the time it took to put together such a thorough explanation!

Comment: @klepp0906 Thank you too!