# how can i output imagemagic image with the name of the containing folder in batch?

Tags: imagemagick, batch-rename

```
FOR /R %%a IN (poster.jpg) DO convert "%%a" -resize 256x256 -background none -gravity center -extent 256x256 "%%~dpna.ico"
```

The current behavior is to grab every poster.jpg file converts it to poster.ico with the specified parameters.
Desired behavior is to also rename it to match the folder name.
examble:
input: folder1\poster.jpg
output: folder1\folder1.ico

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your **`For /R`** to **[`For /R /D`](https://superuser.com/a/1599645/969781)**

---

You can use the `For /D /R` loop, which will go through all the folders, and in each folder inside the loop, use the `if` condition to check if your `poster.jpg` file exist, and run your command if return true.

```bat
for /r /d %%a in (*)do if exist "%~dpnxa\poster.jpg" convert "%%~a" -resize 256x256 -background none -gravity center -extent 256x256 "%%~dpa%%~na.ico"
```

---

- ```bat
  FOR /R - Loop through files (recursively)
  FOR /D - Loop through several folders/directories
  ```
- ```bat
  The option /D /R is undocumented, but can be a useful combination,
  while it will recurse through all subfolders the wildcard will only
  match against Folder/Directory names (not filenames)
  Note: Source linked to ss64.com
  ```

This is the same logic/code from this **[answer](https://superuser.com/a/1627378/969781)**

---

- Some further reading:

  - **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**
  - **[For /D Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**
  - **[For /R Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**
  - **[if condition() else condition()](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**