# Using wildcards with the rd command inside for

Tags: batch

I want to delete all folders starting with "machine.contoso.com" (including all subfolders and files). I tried this command:

I get an error, though :(

```
cd c:\Program Files\Software\Temp
for /f %i in ('dir /a:d /s /b machine.contoso.com*') do rd /s /q %i
```

error:

```
rd /s /q C:\Program
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Folder Structure:

```
machine.contoso.com_1611940173
machine.contoso.com_1611323243
machine.contoso.com_1611645665
machine.contoso.com_1611940176
machine.contoso.com_1611940177
HOSTNAME.contoso.com_com_1811940177
HOSTNAME.contoso.com_com_1813435435
HOSTNAME.contoso.com_com_1811940456
HOSTNAME.contoso.com_com_1811345463
HOSTNAME.contoso.com_com_1813523454
```

thanks,

Comment: you need quotes around the second %i - `"%i"`

Comment: same still issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your **`For /F`** to **[`For /R /D`](https://superuser.com/a/1599645/969781)**

```bat
cd /d  "C:\Program Files\Software\Temp\" && for /r /d %i in (*contoso*)do rmdir /q /s "%~dpnxi"
```

---

You can use the `For /D /R` loop, which will go through all the folders, and in each folder inside the loop, use the `RMDir` command to delete the current folder in the loop and all files/subfolders.

- ```bat
  FOR /R - Loop through files (recursively)
  FOR /D - Loop through several folders/directories
  ```
- ```bat
  The option /D /R is undocumented, but can be a useful combination,
  while it will recurse through all subfolders the wildcard will only
  match against Folder/Directory names (not filenames)
  Note: Source linked to ss64.com
  ```

**Obs. 1** You can use **`machine.contoso.com*`**, **`m*.contoso.com*`**, **`m*.c*.com.*`**, **`m*.c*.c*.*`**, etc... in your loop for loop `..(strings)do...`

**Obs. 2** But keep in mind that you will probably need to run as an administrator to delete items in **`%ProgramFiles%`**.

---

- Some further reading:

  - **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**
  - **[For /D Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**
  - **[For /R Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**
  - **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

Comment: what does mean by `"%~dpnxi"` ?

Comment: Drive Path Name eXtension to %~i